# Reference Blob Image File to Azure Web App with Restriction

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am uploading user images from Azure WebApp to Blob Storage using SAS Token Authentication. This works well.

Now I am referencing image path (through blob url) to my webapp  while showing the same image to user. If I keep my Blob as Public it works well but the problem is - In this case there won't be any security on my user image as anyone can hit my blob url and can download all available images.

One way I know is - Download user image using SAS Token and display it on WebApp but it hits the performance as everytime it has to pass through the authentication.

Is there a way to allow my Public blob access only to my webapp?

P.S. - My application is developed under .NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way that does not affect performance.

Since you don't want your blob to be accessed by anything other than your web app, a verification method like SAS is necessary, which is also method provided by offcial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-secure-access-application

After you deny other access, you need to prove to Azure that you have access to the resource. Therefore, authentication methods such as SAS are necessary.